# Configure Flink use S3 checkpoint with WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider

Tags: hadoop, apache-flink, presto

I am running my flink cluster in EKS, and I need to use the WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider for authentication. According to the doc, there are 2 approaches:

### Presto

I tried setting up this in flink conf:

```
presto.s3.credentials-provider: com.amazonaws.auth.WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider
```

but it shows error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.amazonaws.auth.WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider.<init>(java.net.URI, org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.s3.PrestoS3FileSystem.getCustomAWSCredentialsProvider(PrestoS3FileSystem.java:845) ~[?:?]
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.s3.PrestoS3FileSystem.createAwsCredentialsProvider(PrestoS3FileSystem.java:833) ~[?:?]
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.s3.PrestoS3FileSystem.initialize(PrestoS3FileSystem.java:244) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.AbstractS3FileSystemFactory.create(AbstractS3FileSystemFactory.java:123) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.PluginFileSystemFactory.create(PluginFileSystemFactory.java:62) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.getUnguardedFileSystem(FileSystem.java:508) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:409) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:274) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsCheckpointStorageAccess.<init>(FsCheckpointStorageAccess.java:64) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.storage.FileSystemCheckpointStorage.createCheckpointStorage(FileSystemCheckpointStorage.java:323) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator.<init>(CheckpointCoordinator.java:321) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator.<init>(CheckpointCoordinator.java:240) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.DefaultExecutionGraph.enableCheckpointing(DefaultExecutionGraph.java:452) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.DefaultExecutionGraphBuilder.buildGraph(DefaultExecutionGraphBuilder.java:315) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultExecutionGraphFactory.createAndRestoreExecutionGraph(DefaultExecutionGraphFactory.java:107) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.createAndRestoreExecutionGraph(SchedulerBase.java:335) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.<init>(SchedulerBase.java:191) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.<init>(DefaultScheduler.java:140) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultSchedulerFactory.createInstance(DefaultSchedulerFactory.java:134) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.DefaultSlotPoolServiceSchedulerFactory.createScheduler(DefaultSlotPoolServiceSchedulerFactory.java:110) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.createScheduler(JobMaster.java:346) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.<init>(JobMaster.java:323) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.factories.DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.internalCreateJobMasterService(DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.java:106) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.factories.DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.lambda$createJobMasterService$0(DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.java:94) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.util.function.FunctionUtils.lambda$uncheckedSupplier$4(FunctionUtils.java:112) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
```

As a result, I am using the fall back hadoop solution:

### Hadoop

However, with Hadoop, I am able to successfully authenticate, but it always write 0 length data to checkpoint, I don't really find an error. There's only a **WARNING** in the log

```
2022-10-05 17:24:34,285 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator    [] - Checkpoint 1 of job 1a68f74acf0ccf403693e2f228fa62a6 expired before completing.
 2022-10-05 17:24:34,287 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointFailureManager [] - Failed to trigger or complete checkpoint 1 for job 1a68f74acf0ccf403693e2f228fa62a6. (0 consecutive failed attempts so far)
 org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointException: Checkpoint expired before completing.
     at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator$CheckpointCanceller.run(CheckpointCoordinator.java:2000) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_292]
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_292]
     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_292]
     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_292]
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_292]
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_292]
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_292]
```

I've also follow some suggestion found on google by setting parallelism to 1 but that is not help at all.

Ideally It would be nice to use presto, but for now, I am okay with either approach that would help on the checkpoint issue.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think flink has this provider as per https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-filesystems/flink-s3-fs-presto/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/fs/s3presto/PrestoS3FileSystemTest.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually separate issues:

### For s3a

The reason why it is not writing the checkpoint is because I am using Apache Beam portable runner, and the `--checkpointing_interval` is default to -1 , which means checkpointing is disabled. After setting this to a non zero value, the issue is fixed.

### For s3p

Thanks vignesh kumar kathiresan on flink slack channel!

The solution is to configure

```
presto.s3.use-instance-credentials: "false"
```

and use the `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain` (the default settings), The `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain` will try multiple potential providers and `WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider` is one of it and will be picked up.

This works for me given that I have all my AWS configured correctly.  But for people who starts from fresh, Besides the s3 permission, you would also need `kms:GenerateDataKey`, `kms:Decrypt`as well.